# Bash Input re-direction gives standard input into the command instead of parameter / filename?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I created a file named "com" with the contents

> Chapter*

I then tried to run the following command into bash:

> ls < com

As far as I understand, the shell will take the input
Chapter*
from the file "com" and place it next to ls resulting in something like this:

> ls Chapter*

Now this command should list all the files beginning with 'Chapter' but instead it prints ALL the files in the current directory.

This is also happening with the following commands

> cat < list_of_filenames_to_give_input_to_cat_command

Let 'list_of_filenames_to_give_input_to_cat_command' contain the following contents:

> quicksort.c
>
> mergesort.c
>
> radixsort.c

This should print the contents of each of the above files. Instead it just prints the name of the files as follows:

> quicksort.c
>
> mergesort.c
>
> radixsort.c

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach:

```
ls `cat com`
```

And:

```
cat `cat list_of_filenames_to_give_input_to_cat_command`
```

> Everything you type between backticks is evaluated (executed) by the shell before the main command, and the output of that execution is used by that command, just as if you'd type that output at that place in the command line.
>
> - From [rozcietrzewiacz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/9382/rozcietrzewiacz) answer to [What does ` (backquote/backtick) mean in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-bash)

## Update

Explanation of why you're not getting the expected results follows:

> **Not all commands read from standard input.**  Examples of common Unix
>   commands that never read from standard input: `ls, cp, mv, date, who, pwd, echo, cd`
>
> With the exception of `cp` above, all the above commands have in common
>   the fact that they never open any files for reading. **If a command never
>   reads any data from any files, it can't read any data from standard input.**
>
> ...
>
> **If (and only if!) a command reads from standard input, the redirected
>   standard input will cause the program to read from whatever you attach to
>   standard input.**
>
> - From [Unix Shell I/O Redirection](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8129/02f/notes/redirection.txt)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. 
ls: cannot access cat com: No such file or directory

Comment: @MiteshMS Out of curiosity did you surround `cat com` with `'` (single quotes) or `\`` (backticks)?

Comment: Oh, oops. Thanks! It's working with back ticks now. Would you please explain me why does this work?

Comment: An explanation for the down-vote would be helpful in understanding why this answer is wrong...

Comment: 'grep' isn't a command listed there. So why doesn't the following work:     `grep <search_word <list_of_files_to_search `
but this does
    `grep \`< search_word\` \`< list_of_files_to_search\``

Thanks for your help! [Also, I haven't downvoted your answer, I don't think I have enough reputation to even upvote]

Comment: @MiteshMS I didn't think you had, it's all good : ). The backticks around `\`<search_word\`` and `\`<list_of_files_to_search\`` evaluates those two files to their contents, while just passing `<search_word` and `<list_of_files_to_search` is literally passing two incorrect arguments to `grep`.

Comment: @MiteshMS I just noticed you tried to redirect input from two sources in your first `grep` command. I thought it would be beneficial to inform you that `"You can only redirect input from a single place, not multiple places."` In case you run into an error pertaining to this later on.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this:

```
ls $(<com)
```

`/bin/ls`, like many other standard un*x commands, work with *command line arguments*, not with *STDIN*.

You could write:

```
ls $(cat com)
```

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) do permit syntax: $(< filename) and work quicker than $(cat ...) or `cat com` because work as builtin (no fork).

**Using STDIN for passing arguments**

There is a command `xargs` for doing this:

```
xargs /bin/ls <com
```

But this won't work with wildcard (`*`).

```
echo $(<com) | xargs ls
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. But I'm interested in why my method does  not work and why does your work?

Comment: `/bin/ls` work with *arguments*, not *STDIN*. You could write: `ls $(cat com)`. [tag:bash] do permit syntax: `$(< filename)`  and work quicker than `$(cat ...)` or `\`cat com\`` because work as *builtin* (no fork).

Comment: use `xargs` for using *STDIN* with `ls`... See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

ls does not read its arguments from standard input, but from the command line.

You could simply do:

ls -l $(cat com)

Comment: Thanks. This works too! So do none of the commands take their arguments/parameters from standard input? Also, why does your command work?

Comment: Have a look at this:

`file_content=$(cat file) ;
ls -l $file_content`
Should be easier to understand why it works.

Many commands do accept input from stdin. Try to experiment with sort for example:

`$ sort < file`

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I understand, the shell will take the input Chapter* from the file "com" and place it next to ls

No, that's not what it means.

```
ls < com
```

is equivalent to

```
cat com | ls
```

Since `ls` doesn't read it's standard input, the data from `com` is ignored. The behavior you're describing is achieved, as another answer mentioned, by using:

```
ls $(<com)
```

Comment: I tried the same thing with `grep` and `sort` and both of them don't seem to be reading standard input as their arguments? Are there any commands which do read that?

Comment: @MiteshMS If you want data on standard input to be used as command line arguments you use `xargs`. You pass `xargs` the command and feed it the arguments on standard in.  For example, `echo file.txt | xargs ls` is equivalent to `ls file.txt`